# Leaflet: Illustrate distance along path, like "measure distance" in Google Maps

Tags: leaflet, javascript, distance, web-mapping

In a map in a web application, I would like to illustrate distance along a path, like how it is done with the [measure distance tool in Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1628031) (see attached image).

Is there a way to do this in Leaflet? Maybe with a plugin?

[image: Screenshot from Google Maps showing a polyline path with distance tick marks at regular intervals.]

Comment: There is currently no such functionality in Leaflet or Leaflet plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the plugin [leaflet-distance-markers](https://github.com/adoroszlai/leaflet-distance-markers) (listed in the [Leaflet Plugins database](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers)) which was sufficient for my use case.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just refreshed and published the [leaflet-measure-distance](https://github.com/onaci/leaflet.measure) plugin for leaflet.

There's a demo here: https://onaci.github.io/leaflet.measure/

It does pretty much exactly what you are described, except it doesn't have ticks... PR's welcome!

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, ticks are very important for my use case.